# Python 2.7- fastest way to apply function to 2 columns of a pandas data frame

Tags: python, string, performance, function, pandas

I need to check if a string that is in one column of a pandas data frame is in another. 
Example data:

```
aa=['mma', 'sdas', 'asdsad']*1000
t=pd.DataFrame(aa)
a=['m', 'f', 'n']*1000
t1=pd.DataFrame(a)
t2=pd.concat([t,t1], axis=1)
t2.columns=['texto', 'textito']
```

With a lambda function I get what I need, but it's too slow:

```
t2['veo1'] = t2.apply(lambda row: int(row['textito'] in row['texto']),axis=1)
```

> t2[:10]

```
    texto textito  veo1
0     mma       m     1
1    sdas       f     0
2  asdsad       n     0
3     mma       m     1
4    sdas       f     0
5  asdsad       n     0
6     mma       m     1
7    sdas       f     0
8  asdsad       n     0
9     mma       m     1
```

Is there a way to do this faster?

Thanks.

Comment: You are testing for membership? ```in```?

Comment: @wwii , I want to know if a character is inside a string. So I guess yes.

Comment: Is your DataFrame already constructed that way or are you making it with that structure because you think it will be easy to perform that operation.

Answer (score 1):

If space is plentiful, you could create a new DataFrame by applying `set` to the original.  Then the membership test would be much faster than using `in` with the strings.

```
# setup
aa=['mma', 'sdas', 'asdsad']*1000
t=pd.DataFrame(aa)
a=['m', 'f', 'n']*1000
t1=pd.DataFrame(a)
df=pd.concat([t,t1], axis=1)
df.columns=['a', 'b']

# new DataFrame  using the set of the relevant columns
df2 = df.applymap(set)
# new column based on the membership test
df['v'] = df2.b <= df2.a

>>> df[:10]
        a  b      v
0     mma  m   True
1    sdas  f  False
2  asdsad  n  False
3     mma  m   True
4    sdas  f  False
5  asdsad  n  False
6     mma  m   True
7    sdas  f  False
8  asdsad  n  False
9     mma  m   True
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a comprehension and `zip`

```
t2['veo1'] = [int(a in b) for a, b in zip(t2.textito, t2.texto)]
```

***Better answer per @Ninja Puppy***

```
t2['veo1'] = pd.Series([a in b for a, b in zip(t2.textito, t2.texto)], dtype=int)
```

***Even Better answer per @Ninja Puppy***

```
from operator import contains;
t2['veo1'] = pd.Series(map(contains, t2.texto, t2.textito), dtype=int)
```

---

Per @Ninja Puppy's suggestion.  Using `set` and checking for subset works in this particular situation with single character strings.  However, it would also return `True` for `'www'` in `'word'` which probably isn't what you want.

```
set('www') <= set('word')

True
```

Also

```
set('not') <= set('stone')

True
```

When

```
'not' in 'stone'

False
```

---

#### Timing

[image]

***Special Note***

Thanks to @Ninja Puppy

[image]

Notice that if we assign the `bool` values from the comprehension to a `pd.Series` and let a vectorized operation take care of the conversion to `int`, we can shave off some time.

We can get even more efficient if we import the `contains` operator and use python's `map`

Comment: Probably worth noting here that using a `set` will have different behaviour for non single characters (eg: empty or strings of length two or more - if that could arise) than the other options.

Comment: Just out of curiousity - how does `pd.Series((a in b for a, b in zip(t2.textito, t2.texto), dtype=int)` perform?

Comment: @NinjaPuppy great call!

Comment: Okay - last one: `from operator import contains; list(map(contains, t2.texto, t2.textito))`...

Comment: @NinjaPuppy You're on a roll.  I don't adding more.

Comment: Was it any faster at all though?